# Eliminar una imagen al eliminar un objeto de una lista enlazada a un DataGrid que muestra la imágen

Tags: c#, mvc, imagen, wpf, datagrid

Buen día compañeros.

Tengo un problema con un desarrollo hecho en `Net Core WPF` usando el `patrón de diseño MVC` y quisiera saber su opinión y/o recomendaciones para encontrar solución.

Mi sistema tiene una clase llamada `Empleado`, la cuál entre sus propiedades, existe una que es la Foto del Empleado llamada `ImageTempPath` de tipo string. Ésta propiedad implementa los métodos `Get` y `Set` de la siguiente manera:

- **Set**: Al recibir un valor, se analiza si es un `Path` válido a un archivo de tipo imagen con las características requeridas para una foto de empleado. Si es así, esa imagen se carga en un parámetro del tipo arreglo de bytes llamado `ByteImage` de la misma clase destinado para ese valor.
- **Get**: Se revisa si el parámetro `ByteImage` tiene valor, si es así, se crea un archivo de imagen temporal y en él se deposita la información de `ByteImage`. Al final, se retorna la ruta del archivo recién creado.

Éste sería un ejemplo de la clase.

```
    public class EmpleadoBase : BindableBase, IEmpleado {

        public int IdEmpleado {
            get => LcIntIdEmpleado;
            set => SetProperty(ref LcIntIdEmpleado, value);
        }
        private int LcIntIdEmpleado;

        ///Más parámetros aquí.

        public byte[]? Foto {
            get => LcArrFoto;
            set {
                SetProperty(ref LcArrFoto, value);
                RaisePropertyChanged("FotoSource");
            }
        }
        private byte[]? LcArrFoto;

        public string? FotoPath { get; private set; }

        public string? FotoTempFile {
            get {// Al pedir la ruta de la foto, el valor actual tiene preferencia. Si no existe, se usará la ruta temporal calculada para el archivo.
                if (LcStrFotoTempFile == null) {//No existe el nombre del archivo. Descargar el archivo de manera temporal y usar esa ubicación
                    if (FotoFileName != null && LcArrFoto != null) {
                        if (FotoPath == null) {
                            //No se envió un Path de referencia. Generar archivo Temporal
                            LcStrFotoTempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                            _ = new FileInfo(LcStrFotoTempFile) {
                                Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary,
                            };
                        }
                        else {
                            //Se envió un Path de referencia, colocar ahí el archivo
                            LcStrFotoTempFile = @$"{FotoPath}\{FotoFileName}";
                        }
                        //Guardamos el contenido en un archivo.
                        LcArrFoto.SbSaveAsFile(LcStrFotoTempFile);
                        //Retornar el path de la imágen creada.
                        return LcStrFotoTempFile;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                else {//El nombre del archivo ya existe, usar ese valor
                    return LcStrFotoTempFile;
                }
            }
            set {//Al asignar un archivo, el sistema debe generar el nombre y el Mapa de Bytes.
                LcStrFotoTempFile = value;
                //Primero validar que el archivo exista.
                if (!File.Exists(LcStrFotoTempFile)) {
                    throw new Exception($"No se localizó el archivo: {LcStrFotoTempFile}");
                }

                //El archivo existe, obtenemos el nombre del archivo.
                FileInfo oFileInfo = new(LcStrFotoTempFile);
                LcStrFotoFileName = oFileInfo.Name;

                //Cargamos la imagen como arreglo de bytes
                FileStream oFStream = File.Open(LcStrFotoTempFile, FileMode.Open);
                LcArrFoto = oFStream.FnToBytes();
                oFStream.Dispose();
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FotoTempFile));
            }
        }
        private string? LcStrFotoTempFile;

    }
```

Todo ésto me sirve para almacenar en la Base de Datos como un campo `VarBinary` la imagen y recuperarla desde ahí si la quiero mostrar.

Hasta aquí, todo trabaja bien; el usuario en el sistema selecciona la imagen y la guarda para cada empleado y puedo volver a mostrarla en el sistema sin problema.

**Mi problema** viene por que necesito mostrar la lista de usuarios creados en el sistema en una `DataGrid` y que muestre una miniatura de la imagen. Ésto también puedo hacerlo sin problema, pero quisiera que, al remover la lista de Empleados de la `DataGrid`, las fotos que se crearon se eliminen de la ubicación en donde se creó para mostrarse.

La definición del DataGrid sería algo así.

**NOTA:** Considerar que existen las clases `EmpleadosModel`, `EmpleadosViewModel` (Que internamente crea una instancia de la clase `EmpleadosModel` llamada `LcModel` y `EmpleadosView`.

**La clase `EmpleadosModel` se define de la siguiente manera.

```
using MsLibrary.VCards;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AppMsInvAlmacen.Models.VCard {

    internal class EmpleadosModel : BindableBase {

        /// <summary>
        /// Lista de Empleados disponibles
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Empleado>? Empleados {
            get => LcEmpleados;
            set => SetProperty(ref LcEmpleados, value);
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Empleado>? LcEmpleados;

        /// <summary>
        /// Empleado seleccionado
        /// </summary>
        public Empleado? SelectedEmpleado {
            get => LcSelectedEmpleado;
            set {
                SetProperty(ref LcSelectedEmpleado, value);
                IsControlEnabled = SelectedEmpleado != null;
            }
        }
        private Empleado? LcSelectedEmpleado;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor de la clase
        /// </summary>
        public EmpleadosModel() {
            Empleados = new ObservableCollection<Empleado>();
            IsControlEnabled = true;
            SelectedEmpleado = null;
            EmpleadosTress = new ObservableCollection<Empleado>();
        }

    }

}
```

**Implementación del DataGrid**

```
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgEmpleados" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                    RowHeight="35"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding LcModel.IsControlEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanValueInverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding LcModel.Empleados}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>

<!-- Más propiedades -->

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <Label Content="Foto" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding FotoTempFile}" Width="50" Height="50" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <Label Content="QR Code" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding QRCode}" Width="50" Height="50" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Para ésto, implementé la Interface `IDisposable` en la Interface `IEmpleado`, y en el método Dispose de la clase `Empleado` ejecuto el método `File.Delete()` para eliminar el archivo pero, debido a que el archivo se está mostrando en el `DataGrid`, el sistema marca error al querer eliminar el archivo ya que indica que está en uso.

Pensé que sería tan simple como establecer en `NULL` la propiedad en el Modelo de datos al que se enlazó la propiedad `ItemsSource` del `DataGrid`, pero esto no ejecuta automáticamente el método Dispose de los objetos de la clase Empleados dentro del list, por lo que el archivo no se elimina.

Después, intenté que, antes de intentar eliminar el archivo, actualizara la propiedad `ImageTempPath` a `NULL` e invocar al método `RaisePropertyChanged` para que el `DataGrid` liberara el archivo y luego entonces, proceder a eliminar el archivo. Esto tampoco funcionó, ya que, aunque la propiedad `ImageTempPath` se establecía en `NULL`, en pantalla el `DataGrid` seguía mostrando la foto, por lo que el sistema seguía sin poder eliminar el archivo.

Por último (y en un acto desesperado) intenté copiar la lista a otra variable para dejar la propiedad enlazada a la propiedad `ItemsSource` del `DataGrid` en nulo, con la esperanza de que eso limpiaría la lista, y después, simplemente recorrer la lista copiada para invocar al método `Dispose` de cada objeto empleado... pero nuevamente, el `DataGrid` sigue mostrando la lista de empleados con sus fotos, lo que mantiene bloqueado al archivo.

¿Tendrán alguna sugerencia para ésto que pretendo hacer?

Muchas gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Desde agregar un [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

Una solución al problema de fondo puede ser no guardar las imágenes en archivos temporales y usar directamente el Array de bytes para generar la imagen.

Para esto en tu clase `EmpleadoBase` agregas una nueva propiedad del tipo `BitmapImage`

```
public byte[]? Foto { get; set; }
private BitmapImage _imagen;
public BitmapImage? Imagen
{
    get
    {
        if(Foto is null) return null;
        if (_imagen is not null) return _imagen;

        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using var mem = new MemoryStream(Foto);

        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
        _imagen = image;
        return image;
    }
}
```

Y luego en el `DataTemplate` del Grid

```
<Image Source="{Binding Imagen}" Width="50" Height="50" />
```

Comment: Buen día Yusef. Gracias por la respuesta. Ya había intentado también ésto, pero las funciones BeginInit y EndInit del objeto Image me dieron éste problema: The following compiler error is generated:
CS7069 Reference to type 'Freezable' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but it could not be found. Creo que tiene que ver con usar Net Core... No estoy muy claro.

Comment: Yo lo probé en .net 8 y funciona, que versión estas usando tu?